# Can you develop in kiosk mode on Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I have a chromebit running Chrome OS on which I'm trying to develop a kiosk app for digital signage.

I would like to use an Chrome OS API (https://developer.chrome.com/apps/networking_onc) which is only available in kiosk mode. Is there any way I can test this during development, without deploying the app in the Chrome store?

Comment: You may refer with this [support page](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/6137016?hl=en) for Chrome app development best practices. It is recommended to test in kiosk mode (if applicable) because kiosk mode can render things differently than in normal Chrome OS full-screen mode. You may also check this [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled) regarding Kiosk Apps.